# UDP client multicast : join a group, what address to specify?

Tags: .net, c++, udp, msdn, multicast

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekd1t784.aspx
The JoinMulticastGroup method subscribes the UdpClient to a multicast group using the specified IPAddress.

What address should I specify?

context: I have many computers, which I want to  exchange messages between each other by udp multicasting so that one computer sends a message at once to all other members of a certain group.

also, how do I multicast the message using the send routine of udpclient
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08h8s12k.aspx
?

Comment: It sounds like you need to read some book on networks to at least get some basics...

Comment: You probably want to read http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5771

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While echoing @Vlad's suggestion on general network background, there is [sample code in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekd1t784.aspx) for the scenario you want here.

> The following code example demonstrates how to join a multicast group
>   by providing a multicast address.

Once you have members who have joined the group, any member can call `Send` to multicast to all members of the group.

Working through the MSDN docs to understand the sample code and relate it to your own situation should give you all you need to know for simple UDP multicast scenarios.

Comment: No, you just need to use a valid multicast address as noted in that code comment: `// Join or create a multicast group. The multicast address ranges // to use are specified in RFC#2375. You are free to use // different addresses.`

Comment: I guess http://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xml from here 224.0.0.1 should work.